# How to import created NER to Stanford CoreNLP?

Tags: stanford-nlp

I have created my own NER with the help from this [link](https://nlp.stanford.edu/software/crf-faq.html).

So, I have downloaded StanfordNER, and tokenized and created tsv file from my own corpus, then created NER.

My next step is to import this NER into the CoreNLP.
How do I import this created NER to the Stanford CoreNLP server?
Is there a specific folder where I can paste the NER?

Comment: @StanfordNLPHelp

Comment: @GaborAngeli you seem to have knowledge and experience with CoreNLP. Could you provide me some insight as to what I should do?

Comment: Do you mean you created your own NER model?

Comment: @StanfordNLPHelp Yes I have created my own NER model, and looking to import into the CoreNLP server, but not knowing how to...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to start the server with the `-serverProperties` option and point it to a properties file.

You should include `ner.model = /path/to/custom_model.ser.gz` to have it use your custom model.  Make sure the annotators list has `annotators = tokenize,ssplit,pos,lemma,ner`